# Array out of bounds, index -1

Tags: c, arrays, char, indexoutofboundsexception

I basically want to store a array of student names, based on a given number. For example, if the user wants to insert 5 names, then the array size will be 5. If the user wants to insert 10 names, then the array size will be 10.

I have a method like this to set a name to a specific element in an array.

```
void setNames(char *names){
     strcpy(name[i], names);
}
```

Thing is, how do I do array bound checks? I heard that you can only add when the index is `-1`.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/

Comment: You should use std::vector instead, then you dont have to bother yourself with such details. </cliche response>

Comment: @ash  This is a C question, not a C++ question

Comment: I would have the caller check for 'i' being at or above the available number of elements in the name array.  I would also pass the address of the name array and the value of i  rather than having to place the name array and i in the global data scope.

Comment: @user3629249 the original post didn't make that distinction, hence Vladimir's response with a link to a C++ tutorial. it's since been edited.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** (as the OP indicated he actually wants C):

**C answer**

What you can do is either create a `char` array:

```
char [N][name_length]
```

where N - number "user wants" (I assume the user will somehow input it into your program), name_length - maximum length the name can have (a C-string, i.e. null-terminated string).

or create an array of your own `struct`s (each holding a separate name and maybe some other information).

---

**C++ answer**

A typical way to do this in C++ is by using `std::vector<std::string>` (assuming you only want to store names, as `std::string`).

You then add new elements using using [`push_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) function. And, as vector is implemented as a dynamic array in C++, you won't have to do bound checking.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays don't maintain their own size, you have to do that for them. This is part of the reason why vectors are so much easier to deal with, and why everyone will say "wtf, raw arrays? use a vector". An array is just a contiguous chunk of memory, thats it. a vector contains an array, and lets you use it like an array to some extent, but it handles a lot of the housekeeping details for you.

Anyway, if you really want to use a raw array, then you'll need to pass around size information along with it. C strings are a null-terminated array -- just a plain old array, but the last element is `\0`. This way you can read from it without knowing it's size ahead of time, just don't read past the null character at the end (dragons be there).

Answer (score 0):

When programming in C/C++ (unless using C++11 or newer), you will manipulate arrays as pointers. That means you won't know the size of an array unless you save it. What `char str[10]` really means is `str's address + 10 * sizeof(char)`. You are directly dealing with memory here.

If you want a high level approach for that, take a look at C++11. `std::array` and `std::vector` are there for you. From the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), look how `std::array` is defined:

```cpp
template <
    class T,
    std::size_t N
> struct array;
```

It means it stores its own size and has useful functions as well, such as `size()`, `at()`, `back()` etc.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I modify my code so that it only adds when `index = -1`. Why should it add if `index = -1`? My mate was saying that its good to do this check

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean here. Why do you want to add only when `index` equals -1??

Answer (score 0):

C code needs to keep track of the array size in another variable.

```
typedef struct {
  char **name;
  size_t n;
} Names_T;

void Names_Set(Names_T *names, size_t index, const char *name) {
  // See if it is a special value and then append to the array
  if (index == (size_t) -1) {
    index = names->n;
  }
  if (index >= names->n) {
    size_t newsize = index + 1;
    // OOM error handling omitted
    names->name = realloc(names->name, newsize * sizeof *names->name);
    while (names->n < newsize) {
      names->name[names->n++] = NULL;
    }
  }
  char *oldname = names->name[index];
  names->name[index] = strdup(name);
  free(oldname);
}

void Names_Delete(Names_T *names) {
  while (names->n > 0) {
    names->n--;
    free(&names->name[names->n]);
    names->name[names->n] = NULL;
  }
  free(names->name);
  names->name = NULL;
}

int main(void) {
  Names_T names = { NULL, 0 };
  Names_Set(&names, 3, "Sam");              // set array element 3
  Names_Set(&names, (size_t) -1, "Thers");  // Append to array
  Names_Delete(&names);
  return 0;
}
```